# Creating Bundle for Framework in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-frameworks

I am creating Framework using "jverkoey/ iOS-Framework" using the following link

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#resources.

Here i am able to create .framework part but not able to create bundle for my Framework. i am using Xcode 5.0 and iOS 7.0 . Can anybody help me to create bundle for my Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must select target with bundle type in your project : [image]
2. Then you need just compile that target with `Cmd-B` or `Product -> Build`
3. After that, you can find your bundle here:

   - `File -> Project[Workspace] Settings`
   - Tap on the arrow [image: enter code here]
   - And find next folder `DerivedData -> [YOUR_PROJECT_NAME-Random_Numbers] -> Build -> Products -> Debug-[SDK]`

Also you can just right click on archive in Xcode in Product group and select `Show in Finder`, but it was not the case for me

I followed the steps from repo you linked to create bundle target and then found it with steps I described above

[image]

Comment: I followed your steps, I am able to see my .Framework but unable to see my Bundle. Is anything i am missing?

Comment: user3373798, I've check out the link you wrote and follows the steps from there, than I corrected my steps, it works for me with small fixes.

Comment: its worked for me problem is target selection.i will accept this as Answer. cheers........

Comment: I have one dought, if i make any changes and rebuild project again then bundle update with new changes?

Comment: Yes, you have to copy bundle again from that path if some resources, that it includes, was changed. I suggest you write a script for copying bundle and framework files into some convenient place and run the script from aggregate target

Comment: I added my framework to new project when i try to run the project but giving error like this  ld: framework not found myframework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: See the trick to help Xcode find your framework from the link you mentioned https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#third_parties

Comment: Thanks once again got it

Comment: i added Serenity.bundle to new project and trying to import like  #import<serenity.h/serenity.h>. But i am not able to import to my project.

Comment: #import <serenity/serenity.h>, should be like that, I think.

Comment: I did like that only. One more thing is if i drag .framework folder instead of Bundle i am able to import framework, But when i try to implement Framework method ( Ex:ConfigReader) in project. I am getting following error    "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConfigReader", referenced from:"

Comment: AFAIK, you need to have both in your project. If you did not find solution, try to localise a problem and ask about it here or your colleagues.